# TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined Flutter

Tags: node.js, json, flutter, rest, dart

Kinda new to Flutter and Rest and I encounter this problem

I wanna post something to my local db.json file. I have made a function to do it which is

```
static Future<Event> addEvent(Event event) async {
  final json = await Rest.post('events', data:event);
  return Event.fromJson(json);
}
```

Which called the Post request

```
static Future post(String endpoint, {dynamic data}) async {
    final response = await http.post(Uri.parse('$_baseUrl/$endpoint'),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, body: jsonEncode(data));

    if (response.statusCode == 201) {
      return jsonDecode(response.body);
    }
    throw response;
  }
```

My JSON file more or less look like this

```
"events": [
    {
      "event_id": 1,
      "event_title": "Event title",
      "event_details": "event details",
      "event_date": "2020-05-05",
      "event_category": "Human Dev"
    }
  ]
```

and I got an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined` which will work just fine if I change the `event_id` attribute to `id`.

So... yeah any suggestion would be appreciated. Not really mind if I have to change the name from `event_id` to `id` though I just curious if there is a solution behind it

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Json Response is

```
"events": [
{
  "id": 1,
  "event_title": "Event title",
  "event_details": "event details",
  "event_date": "2020-05-05",
  "event_category": "Human Dev"
}
```

]

"event_id" is not included in that response.That is the reason for that error. http package cannot get the value of the key named "event_id".

Comment: So... a JSON should have `id` attribute then? like I cannot change that to something else?